# Filter nested arrays and objects

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, filter

I have an array containing 2 complex objects:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]

0:
  name: 'item1'
  data:
    fileExtension: undefined
    force_distribution: Array(9)
      0: {Fx: Array(76), x: Array(76), Fxcum: Array(76)}
      1: {y: Array(22), Fx: Array(22), Fxcum: Array(22)}
      2: {Fx: Array(92), z: Array(92), Fxcum: Array(92)}
      3: {x: Array(22), Fycum: Array(22), Fy: Array(22)}
      4: {y: Array(92), Fy: Array(92), Fycum: Array(92)}
      5: {Fy: Array(76), z: Array(76), Fycum: Array(76)}
      6: {x: Array(92), Fz: Array(92), Fzcum: Array(92)}
      7: {y: Array(76), Fz: Array(76), Fzcum: Array(76)}
      8: {Fz: Array(22), z: Array(22), Fzcum: Array(22)}
      length:9
1: 
  name: 'item2'
  data:
    fileExtension: undefined
    force_distribution: Array(9)
      0: {Fx: Array(76), x: Array(76), Fxcum: Array(76)}
      1: {y: Array(22), Fx: Array(22), Fxcum: Array(22)}
      2: {Fx: Array(182), z: Array(182), Fxcum: Array(182)}
      3: {x: Array(22), Fycum: Array(22), Fy: Array(22)}
      4: {y: Array(182), Fy: Array(182), Fycum: Array(182)}
      5: {Fy: Array(76), z: Array(76), Fycum: Array(76)}
      6: {x: Array(182), Fz: Array(182), Fzcum: Array(182)}
      7: {y: Array(76), Fz: Array(76), Fzcum: Array(76)}
      8: {Fz: Array(22), z: Array(22), Fzcum: Array(22)}
      length:9
```

if a user select x and Fx is there a way to easily obtain the following without using a loop? I know how to use filters but I am struggling to apply to nested arrays and objects.

```
0:
  name: 'item1'
  data:
    fileExtension: undefined
    force_distribution: Array(9)
      0: {Fx: Array(76), x: Array(76), Fxcum: Array(76)}
      length:1
1: 
  name: 'item2'
  data:
    fileExtension: undefined
    force_distribution: Array(9)
      0: {Fx: Array(76), x: Array(76), Fxcum: Array(76)}
      length:1
```

Comment: Please, be more precise. How does the user choose x and Fy and why do you then filter only objects containing x and Fx?

Comment: Not clear on the filter logic, either, also do you want to modify the original array or create a new array?

Comment: Sorry, a mistake. I meant user selects x and Fx. I have amended it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me what your filter logic is (you say user selects `x` and `Fy` but example result has items with `x` and `Fx`) but you can always use a `map` and `filter` some things while copying the rest using [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals):

```
const filtered = original.map(item => ({
  ...item, // not needed if top level array items only have 'data' key
  data: {
    ...item.data,
    force_distribution: item.data.force_distribution.filter(/* your filter logic here */)
  }
}));
```